# Show middle of Image on iPhone - Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, image-scaling

I am getting into a dilemma. I am trying to show the middle of an image. I use the the mageWithImage:CovertToSize function to scale the image. The problem is that the image is being stretched height wise. So the question is, what is the correct method to scale an image to 320 pixels wide and show the middle of the photo or close to it?

```
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    Scale *scale = [[Scale alloc] init];
    float newHeight = (image.size.height * 2) / image.size.width * 320.0f;
    image = [scale2 imageWithImage:image CovertToSize:CGRectMake(0, -(newHeight / 2), 320.0f, newHeight)];
    CGImageRef imageRef;
    if (newHeight > 125) {
        imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 125));
    }else{
        imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, newHeight));
    }
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef], 1.0);
    UIImage *cimg = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Edited the post to clarify what the question is and what the problem is. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your not aware of how layers work, http://www.ruttencutter.com/?p=90
If you are, I suggest you have a frame of an image as a layer with the selected area in the middle cut out so that, under that layer, you can put the image there so that you'll only see that selected area.

Comment: This might work in a similar situation, I couldn't get it work in my situation. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: no problem, but do you have the cocos2d frameworks installed? that may be your problem. I think layers come with cocos2d